# Why does Python's heapq's tuple comparison not work as it supposed to?

Tags: python, tuples, string-comparison, heapq

So in Python when I type

```
from heapq import heappush
a=[]
heappush(a,('art zero', 'let3 art zero'))
heappush(a,('own kit dig', 'let2 own kit dig'))
heappush(a,('art can', 'let1 art can'))
print(a)
```

it gives

```
[('art can', 'let1 art can'), ('own kit dig', 'let2 own kit dig'), ('art zero', 'let3 art zero')]
```

Isn't 'own kit dog'>'art zero'? Why does the tuple comparison in heapq not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heap is not the same thing as a sorted list. A heap only guarantees that an element is not greater than the values of its *children*.

The two values you are comparing are *sibling* values. There is no particular relationship between sibling values in a heap. The only thing you can know is that they both are not less than their parent.

To be complete, in a heap the children of a value at index *i* are at index *2i+1* and *2i+2*.

When you would `heappop` values from your heap, you *would* get them in the right order though.

Comment: Thx. That helps. I learned it in college but completely forgot that heap sorts stuff by creating a tree. A heap list would not actually be sorted unless i use heappop.